# Angular2: Cancel Http requests that are in a loop

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-http, angular2-observables

I have a series of Http calls that are made by looping through the gadgets. Is there a way to abort all the requests

```
      for (let gadget of gadgets) {
               this.userService.getGadgetsData(gadget.Id, gadget.Name).subscribe(gadgetsData => {   
    });
}
```

My service code in component.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(public _http: Http) { }
 getGadgetsData() {

        return this._http.get(this._dashboards, { headers: this.getHeaders() })
            .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'abort'? You must see that this._http.get will create HTTP request immediately but return response asynchronously later. You want to abort the actual HTTP request or just unsubscribe the Observable object returned?

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. Either way it is fine, to abort the actual request or unsubscribe. But you see there are multiple requests as the request is inside a loop

Comment: Under what conditions, you want to unsubscribe the Observable object?

Comment: I want to do that in my button click event

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please take a look if this is what you want.

```
observableList: [];

......

for (let gadget of gadgets) {
    let obs = this.userService.getGadgetsData(gadget.Id, gadget.Name).subscribe(gadgetsData => {
    });
    this.observableList.push(obs);
}

...
onClick() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.observableList.length; i++) {
        this.observableList[i].unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add timeout for your request, and then `unsubscribe` from your observables.

Note: I'm assumming you're using RxJs and Observable because of your sample code.

If you have a click event, you can save a reference to all your observables (`inside your loop`) and put them in a list, and then inside your function (e.g. `onClick()`) iterate through that list and `unsubscribe` from all your Observables.

```
    var myObservable = this.userService.getGadgetsData(gadget.Id, gadget.Name)
          .subscribe(gadgetsData => {});

    //later on your code, maybe on your click event

    myObservable.unsubscribe();
```

From the github docs: [unsubscribe](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#subscription-dispose-is-now-unsubscribe) and [subscribe](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/e91d113e49acc9b0e12e2524040fa84cf3fa2c78/doc/subscription.md)

Trying to be thorough:

You can also add Observables to other Observables, so that when you unsubscribe from the main (parent) observable all observable contained within will also unsubscribe. You can achieve it with the methods `add` and `remove` contain in the Observable object.

There could be a better way to do this, but that's off top of my head.

Comment: So where do you want me to add timeout as there are multiple pending requests. I didn't get exactly what you mean. Can you please explain little more.